# Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

[image]

CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Http Context' does not exist in the namespace 'System Web' in asp.net core

Comment: You can refer to the section I posted below and you'll see the versions that HttpContext applied for. And could you pls accept it as the answer if you feel my post is helpful to you so that it will also benefit others who may face the same issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web is not compatible with dotnet core and you mustn't try and reference it. In your case, if you are in a controller, you can access Request and Response properties directly.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) is a class contained in .Net framework but not .net core.

If you wanna access HttpContext in asp.net core, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1), for example, in controller like code below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        var pathBase = HttpContext.Request.PathBase;

        ...

        return View();
    }
}
```

and in other class, we need to inject service then use it, see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove system.web.dll    
//1. install nuget package: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http"
    //2. create readonly property HttpContext 
    //3. create constructor and add argument HttpContext 
    //4. use "_context" instead of "system.web.HttpContext.currrent" in your code 
     
    //property:
            private readonly HttpContext _context;
    //constructor:
            public RegionalizeService(HttpContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be different from the existing answers.